# How can I insert this subdomain filtering in an existing Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

I have an existing Rails 3.2 application that is basically a simple product catalog. Now I am faced with a situation where I need to only allow interactions with specific products based on the subdomain the user is using to access the site.

The `Product` model `belongs_to` a `Repository`, which has the `subdomain` as a value.

So that a request to:

```
http://bobs_store.myapp.com/products
```

only shows products that have a repository with the name `bobs_store`.

Where is/are the best place/places to introduce this filtering? Is there some kind of default scope I can create at the model level to do this? My only problem with that is that I can't access the request from the model, so does this mean that I have to pass the subdomain in to every call I make to that model?

One other thing, all of the calls to the `Product` model are made like this:

```
current_user.products.<whatever>
```

Is it possible to modify my `current_user` helper method somehow to get my desired functionality? Barring that, is there something fancy I can do with routes? These are shots in the dark, but I'm hoping there is some Rails shortcut I can use that I'm not aware of.

Comment: watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As luri G mentioned, watch this Railscast:
[221-Subdomains](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)

Create a scope to query products of a repository

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :repository

   scope :for_repository,
         (lambda do |repository_name|
            includes(:repository).
            merge(Repository.where(name: repository_name))
         end)
end
```

After you had implemented the subdomain route handling logic as per the Railscasts, in your controller you will call the products for a repository like this:

```
current_user.products.for_repository(request.subdomain)
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I've seen it done before is to have a scope on the model, e.g. `Product.repository_scope`.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.repository_scope(repository)
    where(repository: repository)
  end
end
```

I'm not sure about a good workaround for not having to pass in the current repository every time.